# Attempting to add a Disturbance

Tags: drake

I'm attempting to add a disturbance to my iiwa juggling robot's paddle

```
disturbance = self.builder.AddSystem(RandomSource(RandomDistribution.kGaussian, 7,
0.1))
    # print("This is the disturbance", disturbance)
    disturbance.set_name("disturbance")
    adder = self.builder.AddSystem(Adder(2, 7)) #adds two inputs of size 1 each
  
    #add the disturbance to the ball velocity with the adder
    self.builder.Connect(disturbance.get_output_port(), adder.get_input_port(0))
    self.builder.Connect(integrator.get_output_port(), adder.get_input_port(1)) #need to get the ball velocity output port?
    
    self.builder.Connect(adder.get_output_port(), self.plant.get_actuation_input_port()) # need to get the input ball velocity to the plant?
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
DiagramBuilder: Cannot operate on ports of System plant until it has been registered using AddSystem
```

I'm not sure what this is referring to...

Comment: The error is saying that the system called `plant` was not added to `self.builder`.  Can you check that?

Comment: I attempted to add self.plant by using self.builder.AddSystem(self.plant), but it reported the error, "C++ object must be owned by pybind11 when attempting to release to C++"

Comment: That means that you've tried to add the plant to multiple diagrams.  You can only add one plant to one diagram.  There *are* occasions where it's useful to have multiple plants (e.g. you might have a simpler model that your control is designed for), but it sounds more likely that you have a wiring issue in your diagram?  Have you tried visualizing it with `GetGraphvizString`?